# Streambuilder is causing my widgets to rebuild twice inside tabs

Tags: flutter, dart, stream-builder

everyone,
My project has 2 tabs, captain and first officer, in the main screen i have the tabs wrapped around with streamBuilder, so that it will wait until it gets data from firebase and then update it using provider, I haven't fully implemented provider yet as I am confused with riverPod usage in future. Anyways, the problem is it will load fine once, but when i go to the firstOfficer tab and back to captain tab, the init state of captain is called twice, and the streambuilder will download snapshot twice, which i can't figure out why , Is it the layout builder or sth..?

Here is the code

MainScreen calls to check if firebase data is downloaded in provider before updating the tabs

```
class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String idScreen = "mainScreen";
  const MainScreen({super.key});
  @override
  State<MainScreen> createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    print('mainScreen initstate called');
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          final isSmallScreen = constraints.maxWidth < smallScreenSize;
          final tabTextStyle =
              Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium!.copyWith(
                    fontSize: isSmallScreen ? 8 : 12,
                  );
          final tabs = [
            Tab(
              text: isSmallScreen ? null : 'CAPTAIN',
              icon: Icon(Bootstrap.person,
                  size: isSmallScreen ? smallIconSize : largeIconSize),
            ),
            Tab(
              text: isSmallScreen ? null : 'FIRST OFFICER',
              icon: Icon(Icons.person_outline,
                  size: isSmallScreen ? smallIconSize : largeIconSize),
            ),
          ];
          return DefaultTabController(
            length: tabs.length,
            child: Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                toolbarHeight: isSmallScreen ? 10 : 20,
                bottom: TabBar(
                  tabs: tabs,
                  onTap: (index) {
                    if (index == 12) {
                      FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut().then((value) {
                        Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                            context, LoginScreen.idScreen, (route) => false);
                      });
                    } else {
                      setState(() {
                        _currentIndex = index;
                      });
                    }
                  },
                  labelStyle: tabTextStyle,
                  labelPadding:
                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: isSmallScreen ? 2 : 4),
                  indicatorPadding:
                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: isSmallScreen ? 2 : 8),
                  isScrollable: false,
                ),
              ),
              body: TabBarView(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                children: [
                  StreamBuilder<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
                    stream:
                        Provider.of<FirebaseProvider>(context, listen: false)
                            .fetchCaptainData(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
                      } else {
                        return Captain();
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                  FirstOfficer(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is the provider for firebase snapshot i added a print statemtn in `fetchCaptainData`

```
class FirebaseProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> captainSnapShot = [];
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> firstOfficerSnapShot = [];
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> cabinCrewSnapShot = [];
  static final CollectionReference captainCollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('CAPTAIN_DATA');

  Stream<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> fetchCaptainData() async* {
    captainSnapShot = await getCaptainData();
    print('captainProvider called');
    //notifyListeners();
    yield captainSnapShot;
  }

  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getCaptainData() async {
    final snapshot = await captainCollection.get();
    final captainData =
        snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>).toList();
    // print('Captain data fetched: $captainData');
    return captainData;
  }

  Future<void> fetchFirstOfficerData() async {
    firstOfficerSnapShot = await FirebaseServices
        .getFirstOfficerData(); // Retrieves the captain data from Firebase.
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> fetchCabinCrewData() async {
    cabinCrewSnapShot = await FirebaseServices
        .getCabinCrewData(); // Retrieves the captain data from Firebase.
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Now this is the captain class

```
class Captain extends StatefulWidget {
  const Captain({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _CaptainState createState() => _CaptainState();
}

class _CaptainState extends State<Captain> {
 
  @override
  void initState() {
    print('captain init state called');
    super.initState();
    i = 0;
    // _updateGrid();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    if (captainData == null) {
      _updateGrid();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final CollectionReference captainCollection =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('CAPTAIN_DATA');
    firstOfficerData = Provider.of<FirebaseProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .firstOfficerSnapShot;
    return Scaffold(
       ////some code
        ));
  }
```

the problem again, is this print statemtn when i go from the first officer tab to captain tab, the provider and initstate is called twice because of the streambuilder, i tried futurebuilder too, same thing, how can I fix it?

```
captainProvider called
captain init state called
captainProvider called
captain init state called
```

Comment: Don't create the stream in the stream: parameter of StreamBuilder.  Lift the state.  See my video on that: https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg

Comment: Yes but i am using provider with a' context', can't lift the state

Comment: @RandalSchwartz I have already watched your video earlier, yes it has solved other issues with streams. Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

TabBarView calls the build method on the new child each time the tab changes. To prevent this, you can turn each  tab child (Captain and First Officer) into a StatefulWidget that uses the [AutomaticKeepAliveMixin](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin-mixin.html). You just need to override `wantKeepAlive` and set it to true.

```dart
class TabOne extends StatefulWidget {
  const TabOne({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TabOne> createState() => _TabOneState();
}

class _TabOneState extends State<TabOne> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Builder(
        builder: (context) {

          debugPrint('Builder tab 1');
          return Center(child: Text('Tab 1'));
        }
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

This should keep each child from getting rebuilt.

---

I also created a simple state management package as an alternative to Riverpod called [code_on_the_rocks](https://pub.dev/packages/code_on_the_rocks). It's fairly easy to run a future using that package and I have an example in the repo: https://github.com/CodeOTR/code_on_the_rocks/tree/main/samples/flutter_future_data

Comment: Oh! cool, I think i have tried Automatic keep alive mixin already, I will try it again. Also great library. About AutomaticKeepAliveMixin is it going to affect the stream in anyway ? wont update or sth..?

Comment: It should just prevent the StreamBuilder from building again which would cause it to fetch the data again